# Analog control of a brushless motor

Tags: analog, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I want to control a brushless motor via a potentiometer (voltage range from 0 to 12v), with a dedicated ESC but without an external arduino/stm32/esp32 board

There any ESC just built that I can use

Or is best to design it from scratch ?

Francesco

Comment: Get a servo-tester with a potentiometer adjustment knob on it and connect that to the ESC.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase any ESC (electronic speed controller) that has the right drive capability for your motor and that has an analog speed control input.

You may need to divide your 0 - 12 V control signal down to the analog range of the ESC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR1Qgd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Sample voltage divider. The input voltage is scaled by \$ \frac {R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \$ to \$ \frac 5 {12} \$. Adjust to suit.*